# I can't load my CSS-file?

Tags: css

I am PHP programmer now. And I am writing new project. When I want to load file using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://quest.my/" />
<title>Quest The Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css"  /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

But it is not working! It have to wark. I have my own virtal-host quest.my with directory  /style/ with file main.css.

Can you help me? I am idiot?

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug, open the NET tab and see what's happening when it tries to find your CSS file. You may see a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Quest The Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://quest.my/style/main.css"  /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://quest.my/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `/style/main.css` (note the leading `/`).  That will cause the path to be relative to the root of the document (which will then refer to your `<base/>` tag).  Right now it's a relative path, and therefore relative to the location the page was served from.

Comment: What happens if you put the full path to the style sheet in the URL bar?  E.g., [http://quest.my/style/main.css](http://quest.my/style/main.css)?